# How to manipulate the SQLQuery result in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, clob

I am new working on Hibernate, I need some customized query so I am using SQLQuery the following is the code I am using.

```
List getResult(String queryString, List<String> bindList, String className)  {

        SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);

        int i=0;
        for (String value : bindList) {
            query.setString(i, value);
            i++;
        }

        if(className != null)
        {
            sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Class.forName(className)));
        }

}
```

The problem is here is that one of the column values are returned as clob type but the type of corresponding DTO's value matching with clob is String so I have to change that clob value into String. is there any good solution for it?

As far as I know that the sqlQuery has list() method which returns object collections including query result rows. So is there any way I can manipulate that content of that list?

The way I tried is the following. I have three column values returned by executing query, boolean, string, and string (which is converted from clob)

```
List<Object[]> rows = sqlQuery.list();
row = rows.get(0);

java.sql.Clob cValue = (java.sql.Clob)row[2];
String str_value = cValue.getSubString(1, (int)cValue.length());

List<Object[]> rows = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        Object[] obj = new Object[3];
        obj[0] = new Boolean(row[0]);
        obj[1] = new String(row[1]);
        obj[2] = new String(str_value);
        rows.add(obj);
return rows;
```

But the log says 
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to SourceDTO. (kind of expected) What I am thinking is that I think I can manipulate resultant list and returns it with matching SourceDTO. Could anyone have some solution about this?

Answer (score 0):

get the input stream of your `CLOB` object using `getAsciiStream()` and pass it to the `copy()` method.

```
InputStream in = clobObject.getAsciiStream();
StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(in, w);
String clobAsString = w.toString();
```

Comment: Yes I was able to convert clob type to String, but the problem is how to make it matched with DTO I have now. Also, in the code above, what is IOUtils, is this something provided by java default?